# "Unresolved reference: userRecyclerView"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```
userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
```

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userRecyclerView"/>
```

I saw a code tutorial video. When he used "userRecyclerview", it says "userRecyclerview" comes from the second code I post above. But it did not come out when I write "userRecyclerview", also there is a Unresolved reference problem.

Comment: You should declare `userRecyclerView` in an object in your Activity/Fragment. But, to help give more information, can you attach the tutorial source as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like they're using Kotlin synthetics to bind the view.

Kotlin synthetics will generate some extra code that will allow you to access views in the layout XML, just as if they were properties with the name of the id you used in the layout definition.

But it has been deprecated already. So to access your views either use findViewById() or replace Kotlin synthetics

with Jetpack view binding following this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Comment: android {

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
} I add this code in build.gradle, but nothing changes.

Comment: Are you adding this as well to your Activity or Fragment?


private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}

Once added view binding, you can access your views. For example here if your xml is called, result_profile, it automatically generates ResultProfileBinding,

Comment: which you can use to access your subviews, like: 

binding.name.text = viewModel.name
binding.button.setOnClickListener { viewModel.userClicked() 


Use this as reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: I still get same problems after I add code. Can I email you  screen shots to help my code better? Thank you.